# How to hide or remove the Bottom View/ page indicator view

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I tried to google almost everything but could not find the solution.
Please let me know if we can Hide the bottom view of PageViewController.

[image]

i want to remove this yellow view.
Even if i use the properties and change the colour to clear colour, still that portion is visible.This view is overriding my contents.
Ive tried using this

```
[pageController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

but this too did not worked .. :(

Please pLease help me. !!!!

Is This atleast Possible

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using a UIPageControl or a UIPageViewController... your question is quite confusing

Comment: I am using UIPageViewController

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015924/access-the-uipagecontroller-created-by-ios6-uipageviewcontroller This answer should help you